Boost Beast 1.84 server example and clangd warning in QT Creator 13
When I load the following original boost beast 1.84.0 server example into my IDE QT Creator 13.0 (C++20), I get the following warning with clang-tools 17.0.1. How can I fix/work around this and is this a bug/warning in the boost library/example that will be fixed?
Example:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/beast/example/advanced/server/
Warning in Line 167 in original example file (my line is different in 161):

Compiler-Call (cmake generated) (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3):
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-13 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_THREAD_NO_LIB -isystem /home/xxx/projects_cpp/boost_beast_server/extlibs/boost/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wfloat-equal -Wunreachable-code -Wunused-variable -Wshadow -Wcast-align -Werror -MD -MT CMakeFiles/BoostBeastServer.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/BoostBeastServer.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/BoostBeastServer.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/xxx/projects_cpp/boost_beast_server/main.cpp
Note that it compiles with gcc (-Werror active), only clangd thinks there is still a problem (Why does clangd consider the boost header code?).
CMake (Used version 3.29.1):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(BoostBeastServer)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(BOOST_ROOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/boost")

if(POLICY CMP0144)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0144 NEW)
endif()

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)

find_package(Boost 1.84.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost not found")
endif()

message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    -Wall
    -Wextra
    -Wconversion
    -Wsign-conversion
    -Wfloat-equal
    -Wunreachable-code
    -Wunused-variable
    -Wshadow
    -Wcast-align
    -Werror
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Possible solution:
To get rid of the warning, the following could help,
but please review, as I only have dangerous half-knowledge here.
After this at least the warning will go away:
[include/boost/core/detail/string_view.hpp]

Opened the following issue for this:
https://github.com/boostorg/core/issues/170

Can this IDE take you to the declarations of the find? I'm a bit "confused" about the "?" operator, so I'm assuming it's inside the find implementation, not your code.
I'm not even sure how boost does string_view these days; it's fairly compatible with std::string_view. Do you get the same warning when you do the find on a std::string_view?

Someone always downvotes for some minor detail; probably because of your screenshot.

I'd guess the warning is actually coming from https://github.com/boostorg/core/blob/31117ef800e3642d4617c39b316b4d0cf6e574ca/include/boost/core/detail/string_view.hpp#L684. r - data() is ptrdiff_t and npos is size_t. Probably best to raise an issue at https://github.com/boostorg/core/issues with your toolchain details

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

To silence this issue you can change how boost header files are included. Just make sure that boost include directory is under -isystem dir flag instead of -I dir.

@AlanBirtles's analysis is spot on, the warning is due to a sloppy conversion inside Boost Core std::string_view. Note that this is not a real issue unless you can deal with strings over 2^63 characters long.
You can make a PR like https://github.com/sehe/core/commit/0d757123f136aff8f8ebed2c876ce7a2ccd28445 or just report the issue.
Another solution is to make the include a system include, which makes the warnings silent.

But I have -isystem active (See my compiler flags above) for the boost headers and // NOLINT doesn't work either. I find it annoying not to be able to get rid of that.

The fix is probably not enough. Compare my post above, the warning will finally disappear after 3 adaptions. Also, I used "size_type" to be more general.

It's possible that that clang has a different default include path baked in, that might contain another boost header? It's also possible that the diagnostic is a bug due to inlining (which attributes the conversion to the calling code). I remember GCC had a number of issues like that a few years back (mostly around unused variables/uninitialized variables). There's a reason I didn't make the PR: I'm not the one with the problem/able to verify the resolution, and there's likely a dozen similar functions in the same area. However, it is a QOI issue that Boost Core should fix.

I have opened the following issue:
https://github.com/boostorg/core/issues/170
